# How to make all rows in table component stretch to be of same height?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working with Jaspersoft iReport designer 4.7.0.I want to create a table with 3 columns and each cell in the table needs to be stretched to the largest object of the datasource.

I have tried with changing the properties of text element Position-float;stretch with overflow - true,Stretch type - relative to tallest object but it works for one row only.

I want this to effective for **all rows** of the table.

**Current ouput**

[image: CurrentOutput]

**Expected output**

[image: expectedOutputwithEachCellSpacing]

**jrxml used*

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f32dfce1-c0d4-4f20-b896-653e7497d7ba">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <style name="table">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <subDataset name="tabeDataSet" uuid="46e73a3d-e883-4c74-a062-6984cc6dac58">
            <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="street" class="java.lang.String"/>
        </subDataset>
        <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="4a76bbab-d785-49f2-82aa-705ea0a2e0d1"/>
        <subDataset name="Table Dataset 2" uuid="984926ca-9b74-4713-a4a8-25e7e3a32697"/>
        <parameter name="tableData" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
        <detail>
            <band height="191">
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement uuid="6e73c624-495f-4558-bfe4-65a0487825ab" key="table 1" x="74" y="49" width="360" height="52"/>
                    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="tabeDataSet" uuid="dcaeff11-66ee-47b5-af06-d2f183cb5830">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{tableData}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:column uuid="ad308669-ebfb-43ca-b518-326779bbb20e" width="90">
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement uuid="34fe3944-c103-4c85-b509-22df1b589d11" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column uuid="0dbf249d-ee6e-4431-bba2-6d13b610582f" width="90">
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement uuid="886ba9a8-98bc-43cf-9abd-c6fd0410029a" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column uuid="edbd158e-278a-4a5d-98ab-4ea592001ee9" width="90">
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                    <reportElement uuid="59ec1fc2-0a76-4c4c-96b0-7e2b5fbad3df" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <box>
                                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{street}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                    </jr:table>
                </componentElement>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

Comment: please share the report preview with data

Comment: @Rathnayake I have attached the current and expected report output formats.Please have a look and advise

Comment: @Rathnayake Is this can be achievable? Please help!

Comment: sorry for the late. `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` is set row height dynamically based on the data length. so your format not possible in default way. i have no idea about it. please refer Petter's answer

Answer (score 1):

### No

there is no attribute that you can set to achieve that all rows will have same size, when one is stretching.

<sup>AFIK upto version  ‎6.7.0 date of this answer</sup>

Naturally you can manuale increase height in jrxml file but if you like to do it dynamically, you need to do something as:

1. Calculate the height you need looping you dataset in java finding the maximum height of the text using font metrics see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256490/5292302) to understand how font metrics can be used.
2. Load your jrxml as a [`JasperDesign`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) object and then set the new height.

*Crude example*, considering that I have set id on my table component that is present in summary band and each cell has exactly 1 textField.

```
int newHeight = 40;
//Load into desgin  
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("path/to/my/report.jrxml");
JRDesignBand summary = (JRDesignBand) design.getSummary();
//I have set id on my component in jrxml so that I find it quickly
JRDesignComponentElement tblElement = (JRDesignComponentElement) summary.getElementByKey("tbl");
StandardTable tbl = (StandardTable) tblElement.getComponent();
//loop all columns and set new height to both cell and textField
for (BaseColumn bc : tbl.getColumns()) {
    StandardColumn col = (StandardColumn) bc;
    DesignCell cell = (DesignCell) col.getDetailCell();
    JRDesignTextField tf = (JRDesignTextField) cell.getChildren().get(0);
    cell.setHeight(newHeight);
    tf.setHeight(newHeight);
}
//Get my report from design and later fill it.
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
```

Comment: Thanks for the details @Petter Let me try the above suggested approach.